# MySQL does not log slow queries according to my.cnf

Tags: mysql, logging, mysql-5.1, mysql-slow-query-log

I have mysql `5.1.69-log`:

and this settings according to /etc/my.cnf:

```
slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysqld_slow.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes = 1
long_query_time = 1
```

also checked mysql @@global settings:

```
@@global.log_output = FILE
@@global.long_query_time = 1.000000
@@global.log_slow_queries = 1
@@global.slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysqld_slow.log
```

but `/var/log/mysqld_slow.log` not being created and if I create it by myself, it's still empty

can't understand where is a problem?

Comment: Do you have queries taking over 1 second?  The MySQL doc says that you can specify that long_query_time in microseconds - so maybe if you drop the time very low or even to 0 and see what happens then?

Comment: just set `long_query_time = 0.001` to check, `[!!] Slow queries: 6% (2K/45K)`, but still nothing in `/var/log/mysqld_slow.log`

Comment: Any chance there's a Linux permission issue with the mysql group having write access to /var/log/?

Comment: there are also `/var/log/mysqld.log` in /var/log and it's being written without any problem

Comment: sorry, there are can be some permission problem, because I've moved `mysqld_slow.log` to `/tmp` and it works, but can't understand why it was not working in `/var/log`

Comment: Sorry, I work in Windows all day - Mac, a bit in the evenings.  Guess you start by looking at the folder permissions for /var/log and also ensure that mysql is running as the mysql group? (I think)

Comment: yes, mysql is running with it's own group, seems to be `/var/log` permissions